# Searching for tags while parsing Wordpress XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, wordpress, nokogiri

I have an XML file of a Wordpress blog that consists of quotes:

```
<item>
  <title>Brothers Karamazov</title>
  <content:encoded><![CDATA["I think that if the Devil doesn't exist and, consequently, man has created him, he has created him in his own image and likeness."]]></content:encoded>
  <category domain="post_tag" nicename="dostoyevsky"><![CDATA[Dostoyevsky]]></category>
  <category domain="post_tag" nicename="humanity"><![CDATA[humanity]]></category>
  <category domain="category" nicename="quotes"><![CDATA[quotes]]></category>
  <category domain="post_tag" nicename="the-devil"><![CDATA[the Devil]]></category>
</item>
```

The things I'm trying to extract are title, author, content and tags.  Here's my code so far:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("/Users/charliekim/Downloads/quotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.2013-04-14.xml"))

doc.css("item").each do |item|
  title   = item.at_css("title").text
  tag     = item.at_xpath("category").text
  content = item.at_xpath("content:encoded").text

  #each post will later be pushed to an array, but I'm not worried about that yet, so for now....
  puts "#{title} #{tag}"
end
```

I'm struggling to get all the tags from each `item`.  I'm getting returns of something like `Brothers Karamazov Dostoyevsky`.  I'm not worried about how it's formatted as it's only a test to see that it's picking things up correctly.  Anyone know how I can go about this?

I also want to make tags that are capitalized = Author, so if you know how to do that it would help, too, although I haven't even tried it yet.

---

EDIT:  I changed the code to this:

```
doc.css("item").each do |item|
  title   = item.at_css("title").text
  content = item.at_xpath("content:encoded").text
  tag     = item.at_xpath("category").each do |category|
        category
  end

  puts "#{title}: #{tag}"
end
```

which returns:

```
Brothers Karamazov: [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80878518 name="domain" value="post_tag">,     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80878504 name="nicename" value="dostoyevsky">]
```

and which seems a bit more manageable.  It screws up my plans for taking the Author from a capitalized tag, but, well, it's not so big of a deal.  How could I pull just the second `value`?

Comment: Are you scraping (downloading from the site) or just parsing files?

Comment: oh, right, that's a good point.  I'm parsing a static document, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `at_xpath` and expecting it to return more than one result, when the `at_` methods only return the first result.

You want something like:

```
tags = item.xpath("category").map(&:text)
```

which will return an array.

As for identifying the author, you can use a regex to select the items that start with a capital letter:

```
author = tags.select{|w| w =~ /^[A-Z]/}
```

Which will choose any capitalized tags. This leaves the tags untouched. If you wanted instead to separate the authors from the tags, you can use `partition`:

```
author, tags = item.xpath("category").map(&:text).partition{|w| w =~ /^[A-Z]/}
```

Note that in the above examples, author is an array and will contain all matching items (i.e. more than one capitalized tag).